# What is Size in Dynatrace's PurePaths dashboard

Tags: dynatrace

I'm new to Dynatrace and I'm trying to analyze `PurePaths` for application performance. I've searched for it in the Dynatrace documentation but no luck. Could anyone please tell what is `Size` referred here

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size is the actual length of the PurePath, so the number of nodes you see in the PurePath tree when you select the PurePath.

Comment: Here nodes you mean are *Methods* in Dynatrace ? When I drilled down to **Methods** based on PurePaths, I found it to be the *Count* value whose summation would be the *Size*

Comment: No, if you drill down to the Methods dashlet only executed method are shown. A node can be anything on the PurePath, another web request, database call, method execution,.... All those combined are the size of the PurePath

Comment: Awesome. That explains.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you have further Dynatrace questions checkout the Dynatrace community at answers.dynatrace.com There is a very active community there.